# Bash - Printf an array containing directories not displaying

Tags: bash, sed, printf

I find all the directories I need and Display them:

```
mapfile -t sm < <(find /home/user/ -name "sourcemod" -type d| egrep '/home/user/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[0-9]+/csgo/a$

echo "SourceMod directories:"
printf "%s \n" "${sm[@]}"
echo "==============================================================="
```

Here I try remove **/home/user/** using **sed**

```
mapfile -t dir < <("${sm[@]}"|sed 's,/home/user/,,')
printf "%s \n" "${dir[@]}"
```

But I get this output:

> ./main.sh: line 15: /home/user/john/224/csgo/addons/sourcemod: Is a
>   directory

How do I properly display the **dir** array like this:

> user/224/csgo/addons/sourcemod
>   user1/208/csgo/addons/sourcemod
>   user/209/csgo/addons/sourcemod

Comment: Why would you not tell `find` to generate the output properly in the first place?

Comment: As Ignacio says, use the `-printf` argument to `find` to get it to spit out the names as you want/need them.

Comment: I did not use `find` to generate the proper output, because I need both outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
mapfile -t dir < <("${sm[@]}"|sed 's,/home/user/,,')
```

with:

```
mapfile -t dir < <(printf '%s\n' "${sm[@]}" | sed 's,/home/user/,,')
```

You asked it to execute the first directory in the list as a command with the arguments being the rest of the directories in the list.  Using `printf()` echoes each directory on its own line.

Beware directory names containing spaces or newlines.

Comment: It Works by replacing `%a` with `%s` `mapfile -t dir < <(printf '%s\n' "${sm[@]}" | sed 's,/home/user/,,')`

Comment: Sorry about the `%a` instead of `%s` typo — now fixed.